# Argc and argv for external program calling C shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, argv, python-c-api, maple

I'm trying to use Maple to call a C shared library which calls Python. Usually I need to set argc and argv in `main`, but since this is another program (Maple) calling the shared library, I don't have the `main` function (or should I have one?). Then how should I set the argc and argv?

This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shiningsun/maple/rhf.py", line 9, in function
    mol.build()
  File "/share/apps/pyscf/v11/pyscf/gto/mole.py", line 1638, in build
    return self.build_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/share/apps/pyscf/v11/pyscf/gto/mole.py", line 1533, in build_
    _update_from_cmdargs_(self)
  File "/share/apps/pyscf/v11/pyscf/gto/mole.py", line 2297, in _update_from_cmdargs_
    opts = cmd_args.cmd_args()
  File "/share/apps/pyscf/v11/pyscf/gto/cmd_args.py", line 25, in cmd_args
    (opts, args_left) = parser.parse_args()
  File "/share/apps/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1382, in parse_args
    rargs = self._get_args(args)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1364, in _get_args
    return sys.argv[1:]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

Comment: Which arguments do you want to pass?

Comment: Just `argc` and `argv`, since the Python side requires these to run.

Comment: More like, where do you get these from? Does Maple provide these? Do they need to contain anything meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmd_args` module only parses `verbose`, `quiet`, `output` and `max-memory` arguments. Assuming only `output` is relevant for you, you could set the values with [`PySys_SetArgv`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.PySys_SetArgv) just after `Py_Initialize()`.

```
char **argv = {"", "-o", "path/to/output/file"};
PySys_SetArgv(3, argv);
```

Comment: Actually I just tried assigning something random to `sys.argv` inside Python and it seems to work. But there is something I still don't understand, for example I don't have any command line arguments because I run on the Maple end and want to get the output also in Maple. Then what should be the `argv` in this case.

Comment: Just read back the output file. Or don't define an output file and redirect the `stdout`.